# Browser does not render images in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Images not rendered when I use Brave browser but when I use other browsers i.e. Chrome, the images in my app are rendered.

as you can see in my code I created an object that handles all the images so that I can dynamically import those images in my components.

```
const Assets = {
    logo: require('./logo.svg').default,
    spots: require('./spots.svg').default,
};
export default Assets;
```

here is the component that imports some of those images:

```
import Assets from '../Assets/Index.js'

export default function ButtonAppBar() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="fixed">
                <Toolbar variant='regular'>
                    <Button className='button-image__logo' variant="text">
                        <img src={Assets.logo} alt="logo" />
                    </Button>
                    <Button className='button-image__spot' >
                        <img src={Assets.spots} alt="car-spot" />
                    </Button>
                    <Button variant="text" color="primary" size='large'>Login</Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
}
```

other stack overflow solutions say that I should reinstall webpack, this I have done but the problem still persists.

I have also tried clearing Brave's Cache, it does not change anything.

Is it a problem with Brave Browser or React itself and what can I do to fix this?

NB: I used yarn create react-app

Comment: React is pretty browser agnostic, if it works in Chrome then I suspect it's an issue with the Brave browser. What is the rendered result in the Brave browser? Have you used any debugging/dev tools built into that browser to help diagnose the issue?

Comment: @DrewReese I have referenced a local image in the README.md, and the odd thing is, when I push my project, even GitHub cannot find the image files as well.